# JavaScript Add item to array if its not already exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I check in JavaScript if the array already have the item?
Im adding the items to my array with the next code:

```
    const booked_hours = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < apptid_set.size; i++) {
        const book_hours = [...book_times][i].split(" ");
        booked_hours.push(book_hours[2]);
     }
     //alert(booked_hours);
```

Its works well, just in the booked_hours shouldnt be any duplicated item.
How can I do that?

Comment: you can use `Set` instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#examples

Comment: I'm not sure why you're spreading your array here `[...book_times][i]`, it's unneccesary. Just `book_times[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you're adding to the booked_hours array this answer might have to be tweaked but take a look at this.

```js
 const booked_hours = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < apptid_set.size; i++) {
        const book_hours = [...book_times][i].split(" ");
        if (!booked_hours.includes(book_hours[2])) {
          booked_hours.push(book_hours[2]);
        }
     }
```

Comment: I was trying almost the same just to check that the returtn false or true, but it shows that  "{" unexpected in the if line. No idea why

Comment: @DaniMisi, A closing bracket was missing in the if-condition line

Comment: thanks @AbitoPrakash for fixing the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#examples) instead of an array for booked_hours

```js
const booked_hours = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < apptid_set.size; i++) {
    const book_hours = book_times[i].split(' ');
    booked_hours.add(book_hours[2]);
}
```

And to convert it back to an array you can do `[...booked_hours]`